# Cannot read property '4' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to redirect to the detail page of a page using angularjs. At first it goes to the page I want and the data to show is shown. But after three or 5 attempts, I get the error I mentioned above. I've shared snippets of code below. Thank you in advance for your help.

**app.js** code:

```js
.state('app.single', {
    url: '/category_detail/:categoryId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/category-detail.html',
        controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

**controller.js** code:

```js
  var getCategoryServiceRequest = {
      service_type: 'getCategories'
    }
    $http.post($scope.food_categoryServiceURL, getCategoryServiceRequest)
    .success(function(data){

      $scope.food_categories = data;

    });


if($stateParams.categoryId){

        $scope.categoryDetailData = $scope.food_categories[$stateParams.categoryId];

        console.log("gelen Category Detail id no :" + $stateParams.categoryId);
        console.log("Mutfagın adi :" + $scope.food_categories[$stateParams.categoryId].CATEGORY_NAME);

      }
```

**main page** code

```xml
 <div class="list">
      <a class="card" ng-repeat="category in food_categories" href="#/app/category_detail/{{category.ID}}">
        <div class="item item-image item-text-wrap">
          <img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" src="{{category.CATEGORY_IMAGE}}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item item-divider category-design">
          <span>{{category.CATEGORY_NAME}}</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

**Detail page** code

```xml
<div class="list card">

            <div class="item item-avatar">
              <img src="{{user_photo}}">
              <h2>{{categoryDetailData.CATEGORY_NAME}}</h2>
              <p>November 05, 1955</p>
            </div>

            <div class="item item-body">
              <img class="full-image" src="{{categoryDetailData.CATEGORY_IMAGE}}">
              <p>
                ID : {{categoryDetailData.ID}}
              </p>
            </div>

          </div>
```

Comment: What piece of code is throwing the exception? You're missing a bunch of debug information...

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I could not share an answer due to the corona virus quarantine. Solved the source of the problem, thank you